# how to use a typescript interface as an enum?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, interface

I'm working with a [library proto file](https://github.com/Stability-AI/api-interfaces/blob/main/src/proto/generation.proto#L5) that [generates an interface](https://github.com/Stability-AI/api-interfaces/blob/main/gooseai/generation/generation_pb.d.ts#L777), that should be able to be used as an enum:

```
export interface FinishReasonMap {
  NULL: 0;
  LENGTH: 1;
  STOP: 2;
  ERROR: 3;
  FILTER: 4;
}
```

The types are auto-generated from a .proto definition, so its hard to update them to be a basic enum.

now, I can use that in my own `type` def like:

```
export type ImageObject = {
  finishReason?: FinishReasonMap[keyof FinishReasonMap];
}
```

but I'm not able to use it for a comparison, eg:

`if (item.finishReason === FinishReasonMap.FILTER) { ...`

> error: 'FinishReasonMap' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

I know TS enum's are a bit funky sometimes, but not clear how to use this. I think I want something like the opposite of `typeof` to get enum values from the interface?

Comment: It should be `enum` in place of `interface`

Comment: You can't use the properties of an `interface` during runtime which makes what you want impossible. `interface`s don't exist during runtime while `enum`s do.

Answer (score 1):

`TS` is pretty much in the right here.

You are using an `interface` there so the syntax `NULL:0` doesn't specify that `NULL` has value `0`, but that the type of `NULL` is `0`. This, in the end, will force anyone implementing the interface to assign `0`  to  `NULL`.

You can see this in action here:

```
export interface FinishReasonMap {
  NULL: 0;
  LENGTH: 1;
  STOP: 2;
  ERROR: 3;
  FILTER: 4;
}

export class FinishReasonMapT implements FinishReasonMap {
    NULL:0 = 0;
    LENGTH:1 = 1;
    STOP:2 = 2;
    ERROR:3 = 3;
    FILTER:4 = 4;
}
```

The bottom line is that when you're trying to do `FinishReasonMap.FILTER` you are trying to access a type (interface) and that doesn't work at runtime.

I don't know of any way of converting that interface to a runtime value that you can use.

Your most likely course of action is to change the generated code to either an `enum` of an [const object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums).

Comment: interesting ty. why does TS need the extra as like `const x=1 as const` ? This seems a good way to avoid TS vanishing enums which i think are just a compile time construct that vanishes in JS?

Comment: added link to the proto and generated TS results, so perhaps the generator script is at fault here, or could be updated for TS best practices. modifying the CMAKE scripts is a bit hairy tho. https://github.com/Stability-AI/api-interfaces/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt